# Is a DLLEntryPoint / WinMain required to compile a dll using g++?

Tags: c++, dll, g++

I am trying to compile a project into a dll using g++. I am able to compile the .dll and import it into my c# projects successfully. However, I am using this tutorial: http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppGppCreateDll.htm which says you need to include a file such as the following in order to create a dll.

UnitEntryPoint.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <windows.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
  return 1;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI WinMain(      
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{  
  return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I compile this file in addition to the other .cpp files, it does work. However, the dll also works when I exclude this file and have no DllEntryPoint or WinMain anywhere. I do have the functions I want to export wrapped with "#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )" and extern "C".

Can anyone tell me if / why a WinMain/DllEntryPoint is required?

Comment: [DllEntryPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) is optional, pretty sure [`WinMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-winmain) doesn't apply to dlls at all

Answer (score 0):

[DllEntryPoint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) is optional and provides a entry point/main function so to speak for the dll as in it's the first thing that is called upon during dll injection/loading.